# How to use pluralization in ngx-translate without ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler plugin

Tags: angular, angular8, ngx-translate

I had problems with ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler plugin (json files parse fails after add plural forms). ¿There are any alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved to implement a custom pipe:

**Pipe**

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'pluralTranslate',
  pure: false
})
export class PluralTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(key: string, number: number): string {

    return `${key}.${number == 0 ? 'none' : number == 1 ? 'singular' : 'plural'}`;
  }
}
```

**Use**

```js
{{ 'daysNumber' | pluralTranslate:2 | translate:{ days: 2} }}
```

**Messages**

```js
{
"daysNumber": {
      "none": "",
      "singular": "{{ days }} day",
      "plural": "{{ days }} days"
    },
}
```

Comment: Note: This does not necessarily work for all lanuages